# прерывается выполнения скрипта, без ошибки

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность

Есть несколько асинхронных функций которые вызываются вот так:

```
(async () => {
  console.log('1')

  await promisify(updateOrdersToAccepted)()
  console.log('2')

  await promisify(updateTo10)()
  console.log('3')

  await promisify(addOrdersToGoogleSheets)([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
  await promisify(ordersQuantity)('DB_LOGISTIC_STATISTICS')
  await promisify(ordersQuantity)('DB_LOGISTIC_STAT2')

})()
```

первая функция отрабатывает без ошибок и завершается.Все, дальше выполнения не идет.
В логах есть только **1**.
Мб я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Заведите алиасы промисифицированных функций, не нужно это делать каждый раз)

Comment: @vp_arth что за алиасы?

Comment: Ну, `const myFooPromisified = promisify(myFoo)` =)

Comment: Покажите код promisify и updateOrdersToAccepted

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Вот так (грубо говоря) работает promisify
function promisify(fn) {
  return (...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(...args, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

// Промисифицируемая функция должна принимать (err, result) => {} функцию последним аргументом
function someFunc(a, next) {
  setTimeout(() => next(null, a), 100);
}

const someFuncPromisified = promisify(someFunc);

(async () => {
  console.log(1);
  const res = await someFuncPromisified(42);
  console.log(res);
  console.log(2);
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообщем нашел решение сам. В функциях добавил параметр next и в конце функции вызывал его,заработало как надо

Comment: А зачем вы промисифицировали функцию, у которой не было такого параметра?

Comment: Приведите тогда итоговый вариант кода. Со слов не совсем понятно, как это может выглядеть

Answer (score -2):

Думаю как-то так.

```js
function promisify(func) {
  return new Promise((res, err) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    res(func);
  }, 1000);
  });
}

function updateOrdersToAccepted(){
  console.log("call updateOrdersToAccepted");
}

function updateTo10() {
  console.log("call updateTo10");
}

function addOrdersToGoogleSheets(array){
  console.log(`call addOrdersToGoogleSheets with params ${[...array]}`);
}


function ordersQuantity(param){
  console.log(`call ordersQuantity with params ${param}`);
}


(async () => {
  console.log('1');
try {
  (await promisify(updateOrdersToAccepted))();
  console.log('2');

  (await promisify(updateTo10))();
  console.log('3');

  (await promisify(addOrdersToGoogleSheets))([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
  (await promisify(ordersQuantity))('DB_LOGISTIC_STATISTICS');
  (await promisify(ordersQuantity))('DB_LOGISTIC_STAT2');
  }
  catch (e){
    console.log(e);
  }
})()
```

У вас ошибка в попытке вызвать результат промиса когда он ещё не пришел.

```
await promisify(ordersQuantity)('DB_LOGISTIC_STATISTICS');
```

а нужно обернуть результат и потом вызвать.

```
(await promisify(ordersQuantity))('DB_LOGISTIC_STATISTICS');
```

В моём примере promisify это моя функция чисто для примера.

Comment: дождаться результата чего? Промисификации? Это синхронная операция.

Comment: Почитайте пример

Comment: https://github.com/dpw/promisify/blob/master/promisify.js

Comment: promisify синхронно возвращает функцию, которая возвращает Promise, который резольвится, когда вызывается функция next node-style асинхронности `function next(err, result);`

Comment: Я не использовал данную функцию. Лиш показал на примере моей promisify

Comment: Но она не имеет никакого отношения к той, что в вопросе =)

Comment: Ну мне из вопроса было не совсем ясно. Отсюда мой ответ

Comment: А в чем ошибка моя? я что-то не пойму. может объясните

Comment: Вопрос: «Доктор, у меня нога болит», ответ: «да что вы говорите, у меня точно такая же нога, и ничего не болит» (минус не мой)

Comment: я и не думал что он чей-то. Я лишь спросил доводы за минус. А мой ответ не про мою ногу, а на то что как надо вызывать await promisify()() если первая функция возращяет замыкание в промиссе

Comment: Ну, promisify — это широко известная концепция. Это как если бы вы в ответе написали свой getElementById с другим поведением, объясняя им ошибку в вопросе. В вопросе нет той ошибки про которую ваш ответ.

Comment: Удерите скобки получите такой же рузультат как и у автора. А поставите скобки как у меня получите ответ как у Вас. А широко известная концепция не включила меня про100, мои извинения